# C# static function is sending wrong arguments to function

Tags: c#, .net, static, arguments

My code is passing the wrong argument to a function for some reason.

I have a `static` class say class `A` having this function `AddMaster` :

```cs
public static void AddMaster(string ipAddress, int port, List<RegisterMap> registers)
{

    // THIS LINE PRINTS THE ACTUAL VALUES SENT FROM THE CALLER FUNCTION
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("datalog_MB.txt", ipAddress + "   " + registers[0].FriendlyName + "\n");
    
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_masters);
            _masters.Add(new Master().Connect(ipAddress, port).SetRegisters(registers));

            _masters.Last().OnEvent += MasterEvent;

            Debug.WriteLine(_masters.Count + " TCP masters connected");
            Monitor.Exit(_masters);
        }));

    }).Start();

}
```

I have another `non-static` class `Master` having the function `SetRegisters`:

```cs
public Master SetRegisters(List<RegisterMap> registerList)
{
    // HERE THE FriendlyName ALWAYS PRINTS THE VALUE OF THE LAST FUNCTION CALL
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("datalog_MB_1.txt", _hostname + "   " + registerList[0].FriendlyName + "\n");
    _registersToRead = registerList;
    return this;
}
```

The function `AddMaster()` is called in a loop.

The first code logs the following which is correct:

```
# datalog_MB.txt
192.168.0.12   192.168.0.12:Value 1
192.168.0.11   192.168.0.11:Value 1
```

However the second code block prints the following ( See the second value has changed ):

```
# datalog_MB_1.txt
192.168.0.12   192.168.0.11:Value 1
192.168.0.11   192.168.0.11:Value 1
```

**Edit #1**

```cs
foreach (var equipment in MSSQL.GetEquipments(true)) 
{
    registers.Clear();
    
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("dataeq.txt", equipment.IPAddress + "    " + equipment.Name + "     " + equipment.ID +  "\n");
    
    try
    {
        registers.Add(
            new RegisterMap
            {
                FriendlyName = equipment.IPAddress + ":Value 1",
                Register = 2001,
                Type = RegisterType.HoldingRegister,
                StationID = 1
            });
        
        registers.Add(
            new RegisterMap
            {
                FriendlyName = equipment.IPAddress + ":Value 2",
                Register = 2002,
                Type = RegisterType.HoldingRegister,
                StationID = 1
            });

        A.AddMaster(equipment.IPAddress, 502, registers);

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(registers);
        
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("data_reg.txt", json + "\n\n");
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
}
```

*Edit #2**

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h3yn7p

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: "My code is passing the wrong argument to a function for some reason." I think that's highly unlikely. I think it's much more likely that you've got multiple threads modifying the same list, and possibly modifying objects within that list, in a way that isn't thread-safe. (Aside from anything else, your use of `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` is highly suspect - if anything throws an exception between them, you'll never call `Monitor.Exit`.) We can't see the surrounding code which is relevant - if you can provide a [mcve] it will be much easier to help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet `Monitor` i've used cuz of the issue i was facing here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72679914/5437621

Comment: So use a `lock` statement instead - that's significantly safer than what you've got now. Although it's still not clear whether `RegisterMap` is mutable or not, and how you're protecting against *that* being mutated. But fundamentally there's still the same problem: we can only see part of the code, so we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show how you call `AddMaster`? You are calling it twice, right?

Comment: @KlausGütter I've updated my question to add that code as well. I'm also trying to create a fiddle if that helps

Comment: So you modify the registers list in the loop while the started task using it still runs. You could try to create a new list each time instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question with a fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/h3yn7p

Comment: @KlausGütter I tried that in my fiddle and it did work indeed. But I still don't get it why wasn't working

Comment: Because you are re-using and modifying the list while it is still in use by the previously created tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246291/discussion-between-mrid-and-klaus-gutter).

Answer (score 0):

You should not `Clear` the `registers` - recreate it:

```cs
List<RegisterMap> registers = null;
foreach(var equipment in equipments) 
{
    registers = new List<RegisterMap>(); 
    ....
}
```

Otherwise you are processing the same instance of `List<RegisterMap>` in parallel in multiple threads while manipulating it (i.e. thread which has the `foreach(var equipment in equipments)` loop will run and create all the threads and start them), which can lead to a lot of different concurrency issues.

Also some notes:

1. Consider using concurrent collections, for example [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-6.0) instead of `Monitor` + `List` (because in current code it makes `Thread`/`Task` handling pointless)
2. Based on the provided code there is no need to create `Thread` - tasks should be enough. In modern .NET there is rarely a case when you need to create `Thread`s manually, most of the time it is hugely discouraged ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429164/2501279)).

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason? Shouldn't it run synchronously?

Comment: @mrid why it should run synchronously? You are not blocking the loop which creates tasks/threads and it will clear and refill list on every iteration.

Comment: AddMaster will create a task (TaskFactory.StartNew) which then runs asynchronously (and it creates this task even unneccessarily from a separate thread, so "double-asynchrounously").

Comment: Aah I think my understanding of the loop may be wrong. I thought the code block would run one iteration after the other and each time the first line would reset the registers

Comment: @mrid if you want it blocked, why do you need `Thread`/`Task` at all?

Comment: @GuruStron so the classes `A` and the one with the function `AddMaster` are working on networking so need to be async. I was just thinking of initializing these classes one by one. Thereafter they can run in parallel.

Comment: @GuruStron also I have one small doubt. If everytime the wrong set of registers are being sent why does the `AddMaster` print the correct registers but `SetRegisters` prints wrong in my fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/h3yn7p

Comment: @mrid because `AddMaster` prints before the collection is changed. And `SetRegisters` - after.